# Why do computers like powers of 2?

Tags: performance, binary

I noticed that programs and people round things up to powers of 2; 32, 16, 64 etc. The common answer, of course, is that it's due to the fact that computers run in binary, and this makes it easier for them to run. But I'm failing to understand this in the more specific sense? Is it at the fundamental degree; do logic gate systems have a preference to powers of 2? Or is it in the operations; are operations too complicated for non-powers of 2? Or is it elsewhere, or a misconception?

A comparison between what a computer would do in some (applicable) scenario involving a power of 2, and a non-power of 2 would illustrate this well.

Comment: same reason that people like the powers of 10 ...... a computer has only two fingers for counting

Comment: write 2, 32, 16, 64 in binary

Comment: I mean sure, I can write those in binary more easily; but it's not as if those are the only numbers a computer would have to deal with.

Comment: you round the same way in decimal .... for example, decimal 100 ... the values below 100 range from 0 to 99 ...... now look at binary ... decimal 64 in binary for example .... the values would range from 0 to decimal 63 ........... write 63 in binary, what do you see? .... write 99 in decimal, what do you see?

Comment: So computers round more easily?

Comment: But even then; computers don't do calculations the same way we do. What do they literally do?

Comment: they do the same thing ... for example take the highest digit value in decimal and add one ... you get 9 + 1 ... because there is no higher digit value than 9, you have to carry one to the 10's ... that gives you 9 + 1 = 10 .... same way in binary ... highest digit value is 1 ... that gives you 1 + 1 = 10    .... if you use octal numbering system, then the highest digit value is 7 ... 7 + 1 = 10

Answer (score 0):

The processor is built using transistors, which are either on (1) or off (0). So they have two states. If you are calculating something with a number that is a power of 2, the processor can calculate it much faster.

For more information, I recommend you to watch some of Ben Eater's videos:
https://www.youtube.com/user/eaterbc